# Model is null on post back in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to generate a list of checkboxes and post the selected item to post method of my controller but my view model is null.

Please see below code and help.

The view get invoke with the following button on another page -

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="historicalrecords"  
        onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("HistoricalWorkSubmissions", "Main", new {id= @Model.MessageIdsCombined.FirstOrDefault()})'">View Historical Works</button>
```

Model `WorkSubmissions.cs`:

```
public class HistoricalWorkSubmission
{
    public string Society { get; set; }
    public string Rsa { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProcessingTime { get; set; }
    public bool isSelected { get; set; }

}

public class HistoricalWorkSubmisssionViewModel
{
    public List<HistoricalWorkSubmission> Submissions { get; set; }
}
```

Get method in `MainController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> HistoricalWorkSubmissions(string id)
{
    WorkSearchViewModel workSearchViewModel = new WorkSearchViewModel
            {
                MessageId = id
            };

    var workSubmissions = await _swvManager.SearchAllWorkSubmissionsAsync(workSearchViewModel).ConfigureAwait(true);

    return View("~/Views/Main/HistoricalWorkSubmissions.cshtml", workSubmissions);
}
```

`HistoricalWorkSubmissions.cshtml`:

```
 @model SWV.WorkPicture.UI.Models.HistoricalWorkSubmisssionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "HistoricalSubmissions";
}

<h2>HistoricalSubmissions</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("HistoricalWorkSubmissions", "Main", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <fieldset>
        <div>
            <table class="table-bordered">
                @*@foreach (var submission in Model.Submissions)*@
                @for (int i=0; i < Model.Submissions.Count(); i++)
                {
                    var bmiWorks = Model.Submissions[i].Society + Model.Submissions[i].Rsa + "   " + Model.Submissions[i].ProcessingTime;
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Submissions[i].isSelected)
                            @Html.Label(bmiWorks)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Submissions[i])

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <input class="button btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save"/>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

And finally post method:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> HistoricalWorkSubmissions(HistoricalWorkSubmisssionViewModel workSubmissions)
{
    WorkSearchViewModel workSearchViewModel = new WorkSearchViewModel();
    workSearchViewModel.SwvId = "5124cfb4-afe8-4783-ab97-b9fbaaf6737d";

    var workPicturesx = await _swvManager.SearchAllWorkSubmissionsAsync(workSearchViewModel).ConfigureAwait(true);
           
    return View("~/Views/Main/HistoricalWorks.cshtml");
}
```

POST-
[image: Post]

The value of `abc` is null in debugger. Please help.

Comment: try add where value is from? GetHistoricalRecordsAsync([FromForm] BmiAndAscapSubmisssions abc)

Comment: Show us your model in the question.

Comment: @derloopkat I have cleaned the code and added the model.

Comment: @daremachine I do not understand.

Comment: @NKM Instead of foreach use for, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60361830/2516718

Comment: Where is `abc` defined ?! Also place what's your trace results

Comment: @derloopkat even using "for" does not solve the issue.

Comment: please check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the field names in the post match the model. The Label is not an issue, but `CheckBoxFor` and `HiddenFor` would generate Html `input` tags in the form posted to server.

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => Model.Submissions[i].isSelected)
@Html.Label(bmiWorks)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Submissions[i].Society)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Submissions[i].Rsa)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Submissions[i].ProcessingTime)
```

Also I've removed the hidden field for `submission` because it's an object in your model, while we need to generate tags for each property instead.